# WSDL authentication

Tags: php, authentication, wsdl

I am first time working with WSDL (no matter which coding language) and I am trying to call one api from it.
 
I have wsdl specification
https://testsportmidoffice.iedu.sk/Services/Sys/Codebook.svc?singleWsdl
I have username and password
And I have tried it multiple times, one of the tries:

```
$wsdl_codebook = "https://testsportmidoffice.iedu.sk/Services/Sys/Codebook.svc?singleWsdl";
$client_codebook = new SoapClient($wsdl_codebook, array("trace" => 1));
$header = new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', 'AuthHeader',  array('Login' => $auth_login, 'Password' => $auth_password));
$client_codebook->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
$sportListParam = array (
    'LanguageID' => 'sk'
);
$result = $client_codebook->__soapCall("GetSportList", $sportListParam);
```

Can someone help me why it's not working? Seems that this is an issue with authentication

Comment: what do you need help with? ... i do not see a description of the problem

Comment: To help with the authentication php code... It's not working properly...